# How can I write simulated data for various runs in different columns of excel

Tags: r

I tried to store simulated data in different columns for different runs of stochastic simulation into Excel using R. I am using the  tau leap Gillespie method to run the stochastic simulation.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.